# File copy from Gallery pick image to Internal Application Picture Directory Android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-camera-intent, android-image-capture

Getting image Content from Gallery picture
 Now, I want to copy this `image file`(Which is picked from gallery) to my Internal App folder  PICTURE directory(`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MYApppackage/files/Pictures/`).

I am creating `new File` in `PICTURE Directory`.  file is created in internal `AppDir / data / Pictures Directory` and image with `.JPG` format  but not showing image. Image is not visible. Image file is created with `0KB` data.

I think its a file writing related issue or other i dont know.

```
 Intent intent ;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                MainActivity.state = "AddBalance";

                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GALLERY);
            } else {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("image/*");

                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GALLERY);
            }
```

OnActivity Result of Gallery PickUp

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
 case REQUEST_GALLERY:
            if (data != null) {


if (data != null) {
                Bitmap bitmap=null;
                uri1 = data.getData();
       //         showPhotoDialog(uri1);
                try {
                //    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri1);
                    InputStream image_stream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri1);
                     bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_stream);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.e(TAG,"Data URI----"+data.getData());
                    try {
                        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                        String imageFileName = "PNG_" + timeStamp + "_";
                        File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                        File image = File.createTempFile(
                                imageFileName, //  prefix
                                ".PNG",        //  suffix
                                storageDir    //   directory
                        );

                     //   File imageFile= new File(storageDir,imageFileName);
                        FileOutputStream out;
                        try {
                           // out = getActivity().openFileOutput(image.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            out = new FileOutputStream(image.getName());
                          /*  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                           out.write(byteArray);*/
                           bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                            out.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
//         copyFile(new File(getRealPathFromURI(uri1)), image);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

            }

            }`
     }
```

**Edit** :  Infos

getting value of uri1 from pickup gallery image : `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A25877`

I am Trying to write bitmap to File.  Here is my Code. `getBitmap` from `REQUEST_GALLERY` and `URI`  works fine . I am making File  in `Enviroment.PICTURE` directory and write via `OutPutStream`.  but Still File :  `PNG_54342323111.PNG`

I also tried with `ByteArrayOutputStream` which you can see in comments but didnt works. also tried with `OpenFileOutput` but not working.

Comment: check log whether it shows any exception

Comment: Ohh Yes its shows at file not open at  `f.createnewFile`

`java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)`

Comment: that means not creating file  in `onActivityResult`   from capture uri
`File f = new File(String.valueOf(uri1));`

Comment: your url isnt correct chk your URI

Comment: `f.createnewFile`. If that fails you should have mentioned us the value of `f.getAbsolutePath()`. I think that path has been mentioned in the exception message too but you omitted it. For the rest you better remove that statemant as it serves nothing and works confusing. The file will be created by new FileOutputStream.

Comment: `getRealPathFromURI`. That is a pretty bad function and you fail to mention the value of the returned path. Do away with this function. You better open an InputStream from the uri directly.

Comment: Can you just put that code or link related read that file data and write on another file.

Comment: You did not give the info i asked for. Very strange. Your problem is posted weekly. You are number #### with this problem. You are not alone ;-). If you just would read a couple of pages tagged `android` you would soon find a solution.

Comment: You can see Edit.

Comment: any update on this issue?